# How to use string playerprefs with TextMeshPro?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I have been following a tutorial for saving player names with playerprefs.
I got it working normal text, but not with TextMeshPro. Is there a way to edit the code so that I can use TextMeshPro with the scripts?

First Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField textBox;

    public void ClickSaveButton()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("name", textBox.text);
        Debug.Log("Your name is " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("name"));
    }
   
}
```

Second Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NameScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text NameBox;
    void Start()
    {
        NameBox.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What error you got when you use TextMeshPro instaed of Text? TextmeshPro have all Text Class features plus more. You can get text from TextMeshPro by Textmeshpro.text, it is same. Just add using TMPro; . Also if it is ui object you should use TextMeshProUGUI instead of Text , if not just use TextMeshPro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import TextMeshPro to your script and instead of `public Text NameBox;` use `public TMP_Text NameBox;`